# Static hub method isn't sending data to client

Tags: knockout.js, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm just getting started with SignalR so I'm most probably doing something stupid.

I have an external task completing work and every time it completes a cycle it calls a static hub method which sends some updated results to the website. As you can see below I'm sending the static method the updated stats row and just trying to write the row out to the console for testing purposes.

Server side codes looks like this:

```
public static void UpdateStats(Stats stats)
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatsHub>();
    context.Clients.All.updateStats(stats);
}
```

Client side code looks like:

```
statsHub.client.updateStats = function (stats) {
    console.log(stats);
}
```

I'm using SignalR to do the initial Page load which is working fine.

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
   statsHub.server.getAll();
});
```

The document ready looks like:

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
var statsHub = $.connection.statsHub;


var viewModel = new ScraperViewModel(statsHub);

statsHub.client.updateStats = function (stats) {
    viewModel.UpdateStats(stats);
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
    statsHub.server.getAll();
});
```

**Update**

Just to confirm  - I'm using SignalR - 1.01 (I've tried 1.0.0). I've commented out the Knockout code so it's just SignalR. Tried it on IE as well as Chrome. And there isn't any errors in the log console log when logging is on.

Comment: Why do you call `statsHub.server.getAll();` in your `start()` callback? Is working without it?

Comment: getAll does the initial pull down of all the stats. if it's outside it then I was getting an error that I was calling it before I was connected.

Comment: And it still doesn't work if I remove it completely.

Comment: Is your `updateStats` handler defined before your call to `start()`?

Comment: yeah - I updated the question with my document ready.

Comment: If you remove the use of knockout and simply log everything to the console, is the communication OK?

Comment: still the same - the getAll is triggered when the page loads but the static updateStats is never called even though the I can see the code being sent their every 10-20 seconds from the server side.

Comment: Is Stats serializable?  Ie, could the server be having trouble serializing it in order to broadcast it to the clients?  Maybe try this out with a more primitive data type first just to rule out the possibility . . .

Comment: Also, are you on the latest (>1.0) version of SignalR?  I think there was a version change where the older syntax used to be "context.Clients.updateStats(stats);" but now it's "context.Clients.All.updateStats(stats);" . . . the trouble with dynamic typing is that the compiler is no help . . .

Comment: In the example above it's using the Clients.All.updateStats(stats). And I changed it to use a primitive and I still get the same results. (Plus I can send a list of stats when I run the getAll() initially)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I redesigned the back end task to connect to a Hub Proxy and update the stats by invoking a method.

The issue may have been I was calling the static hub method from an external dll?